# problema de seguridad en javascript y php 8

Tags: javascript, php, php8

tengo un problema de seguridad segun veo, los id de la aplicacion los enumere de la siguiente forma, supongamos seccion de pais, cuando el usuario va a seleccionar el pais, en el select tengo en value el ID y bueno luego el nombre del pais, como el siguiente ejemplo.

```
       <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="tipo_produc"  id="tipo_produc" onChange="pais_product();" required>
 <option value=0>Seleccione tipo de producto</option>
 <option value=1>Pago de servicios</option>
          <option value=2>Transferencias</option>
          <option value=3>Pago a usuarios</option>
         <option value=4>Market</option>
</select>
```

ahora lo que veo es que el usuario malicioso puede editar esos id y cambiarlos desde el inspector de elementos, supongamos que va a realizar una transacción por peru, puede cambiar ese ID por ejemplo y colocar el de ecuador, a pesar que me es indiferente por que estaría editando seria solo sus datos pero de igual forma me preocupa, me dicen que tengo que codificar eso asi como codificar también donde el usuario inicia sesión a pesar que tengo mis consultas en php 8 ya preparadas y las variables las tengo satinizadas, que recomendaciones me darían para mejorar en este punto la web o que se podría hacer?, quiero tratar de mejorar la parte de seguridad ya que eso me da algo de miedo, esos de lo que puede hacer un usuario malicioso.

Comment: Hola, en el texto indicas un `select` de pais pero en el HTML muestras el `select` de tipo de producto, te recomiendo colocar el código correcto y completo para apoyarte y darte un ejemplo más preciso.

Comment: Por que tendría que  suponer un problema ?  El `usuario mal intencionado`   Podría modificar el código del `select ` vía `Inspector de elementos` pero realmente podría hacer lo sin el. Solo debe marcar otra opción.   Ahora, si el ´Usuario mal intencionado´   cambia un valor   por uno que no existe.  Lo que podría pasar es : Al momento de guardar la información tengas en tu base de datos ´tipo_produc = 1000´.    ¿Qué  pasa después?   El usuario pagaría por lo que selecciono   `Nada` por `Ningún producto`

Comment: ok Wilfredo te explico la situación, tengo un select que contiene a PRODUCTOS, VEHICULOS Y SERVICIOS, cuando seleccionas productos aparece para que agregues todo lo relacionado  productos, si seleccionas vehículos, agregarías lo referente a vehículos,  ahora digamos que el usuario me selecciona productos, rellena todos los demás datos del formulario y antes de darle enviar me modifica el valor de productos y coloca el id de servicios, entonces me guardaría a ese producto como si fuera un servicio en esa tabla.

Comment: Vale . Entonces solo debes validar al momento de guardar, si el código del servicio enviado `existe` en la `tabla de servicios`.  No es un problema de seguridad  es un problema logico.   Seria un  problema de seguridad : si el usuario podría hacer un `inyeccion SQL` mediante el `value` del `select`

Comment: Ah tienes razon, muchas gracias, ya voy a cambiar entonces esa parte del codigo